# What are the exact effects of luck?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

From what I read here and there, luck has the following effects:

> - Increase critical strike chance
> - Increase mob (item/shards) and destructible objects drop rates

Not sure that it affects chests that reappear...

**Does anyone know the exact effect ?** (an approximation would be nice as well)
Is there a soft cap ?